# Need to reload browser to see notification length

Tags: angular, notifications, angular-httpclient

I am making a notification and i have a "bell" icon that has a badge. That badge shows how many notification i have. I determine by array length. My problem is that i need to reload the browser just to see the update of new notifications. I can only see the changes in the badge when i reload the browser. Is there anything missing in my code?

> TS

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllNotifs();
  }

  getAllNotifs(){
    this.notificationsService.getAll()
    .subscribe(
      (data:any) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.notifications = data.notifications;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

> HTML

```
 <i class="bell"></i>
 <span class="badge" *ngIf="notifications?.length>0">{{notifications.length}}</span>
```

Comment: Why do you think it should automatically update in the first place? How many times is ngOnInit called? How many HTTP requests does it send, and thus how many HTTP responses does it receive?

Comment: @JBNizet. Ive attached it in the navbar so it calls everytime i navigate or everytime a function calls

Comment: Err, no. ngOnInit is called once, when the component is created. https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you're only making the HTTP once, in `ngOnInit`.

Instead, if you want it to update, you'll need to set up polling.

To do this, you can make use of `setTimeout` to call the function recursively, like so:

```
  timeout: Number;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.getAllNotifs();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
      // Clear the pending timeout so it doesn't keep running
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
  }

  getAllNotifs(){
     this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.notificationsService.getAll()
        .subscribe(
          (data:any) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.notifications = data.notifications;
            // Call recursively
            this.getAllNotifs();
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
     }, 5000);
  }
```

Comment: I think you mean Interval, setTimeout will execute once after the specified time. So it won't change the behavior of the current problem, just delay it.

Comment: No, I mean't to use `setTimeout`. I'm calling this function recursively. By using `setTimeout`, I can make sure it's always 5 seconds from when it returns, not just every five seconds. It prevents the server from being overloaded

Comment: This will, however, stop getting modifications as soon as one request fails (like when going through a tunnel in the train, for example)

Comment: Very true. If may be a good idea to add some retry logic into the error handler as well (possibly depending on the type of error)

Comment: Or simply to call setTimeout inside a finalize operator.

Comment: @user184994. Will it not crash my browser?

Comment: @Joseph that, and bring your house to flames, and cause an earth-quake destroying the whole city :-) No, seriously, why would sending a request every 5 seconds crash your browser? Overload your server, if you have many concurrent users and computing the number of notifications is slow, maybe. But crash the browser? Why?

Comment: @JBNizet. Will it not result in error code 429 Too many request?

Comment: @Joseph It depends on what throttling you have on your backend. If so, you can change it from polling every 5 seconds to whichever value you think is best (maybe 30 seconds, maybe 60, it depends on how accurate and up-to-date you need the value to be)

Comment: @user184994. Is there a way that i could call the function getAllNotifs() in the sidebar, whenever there's  a get or post request. Will i handle it in the http interceptor. If yes, how will i able to call it from the http interceptor. I really like it to be realtime but if put setTimeout or setInterval seconds on it, it produces error 429. Thank you.

Comment: If you want it to be realtime, I would suggest looking into websockets

Comment: @user184994. Can i do it without using websockets? Can i just run the getAllNotif()  whenever there's a get or post request.

Comment: You could try creating a shared service that contains an observable. Inject it into your interceptor, and emit a value each time you want to reload. Subscribe to that observable within your component, and each time a value is emitted, you can make a new `getAllNotif()` call

Comment: @user184994. Can you help me with that? i want to implement that in the sidebar. Thanks

Comment: Which bit do you need help with?

Comment: @user184994. the one which you can update the sidebar getAllNotifs() function whenever there's a post or get request

Comment: Do you know how to use Observables? Once you've created your observable, you just need to subscribe, and call `getAllNotifs` from within the `subscribe` function

Comment: @user184994. I mean how can i call the getAllNotif() so that the notifications.length will update. The sidebar ngOnInit() runs only once.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1pdfbt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts). You can inject the `ExampleService` anywhere, and when you call its `.notify()` function, the notifications will update in the `HelloComponent`